# Is it possible to continue tests sequentially from prior test state with Foundry/Forge?

Tags: testing, rust, ethereum, solidity

I'm wondering if there is a way within Forge to continue your tests sequentially, starting from the contractual end state of the last test without repasting the prior tests code as setup. Obviously I could just make one massive test, however, i would lose the gas data and such that i would receive from individual tests. Thank you in advance to anyone who can help :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Each test is run in isolation, with the exception that state from `setUp` is preserved.

You *can* make a bigger test and retain gas reporting information if you use `forge test --gas-report` instead of going by the gas reported by just `forge test`. The `--gas-report` flag uses transaction tracing to build a gas usage report of individual calls instead of the entire test.